# combinations in sql without repetitions

Tags: mysql, sql

Use case:

Table_name : Teams. it has 1 column "Country)

```
Country
India
lanka
aus
```

Now I need to create a new table with 2 columns "Team 1" and Team 2" which generates the matches.

Example:

```
Team1     Team2        
Ind       Lanka
Ind       Aus
```

Ignoring the create table and insert table queries, here is my select query to accomplish this:

```
SELECT distinct
s1.Country as sk, 
s2.Country as sk2
from Teams s1 cross join Teams s2
where sk <> sk2
```

I am able to get a partial output, but my problem is the above query contains op like below:

```
Team1     Team2
India      Aus
Aus        India
```

but in the scenario these are two same matches. Any suggestions on how to correct this mistake is appreciated.

Comment: you want the query result to have each team(country) once in the results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<`:

```
select s1.Country as sk, s2.Country as sk2
from Teams s1 join
     Teams s2
     on s1.sk < s2.sk;
```

Note that you cannot use column aliases in the `where` clause.  Instead, qualify all column references.

If `country` is repeated in the table, then use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct s1.Country as sk, s2.Country as sk2
from Teams s1 join
     Teams s2
     on s1.sk < s2.sk;
```

But if the countries are unique, don't bother.  `select distinct` is more expensive than `select` and should only be used when needed.

Comment: can you explain what exactly is this '<' operator doing here?

Comment: That operator is a comparison.  The SQL statement is doing a self-join on Teams, keeping only rows where s1.sk is less than s2.sk.